# Set multiple items for an argument in embeded view

Tags: views

I'm using this code to display a view inside a node:

```
$view_args = array($node->field_page_cck[0]['value']);
$view = views_get_view('my_view');
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->set_display('default');
if (!empty($view)) {
    print $view->execute_display($display_id , $view_args);
}
```

The argument is set with the option **Allow multiple arguments to work together.**

I tried with:

```
$view_args = array($node->field_page_cck[0]['value'], $node->field_page_cck[1]['value']);
```

but no luck.

I also tried to convert to a string like this: argument1+argument2+.... or argument1,argument2,.... still no luck.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2):

The argument itself needs to be configured to take multiple items. There is a checkbox which says "Allow multiple terms per argument".

[image]

After that you should be able to have a string with commas separating them

```
$view_args = array($node->field_page_cck[0]['value'] . ',' . $node->field_page_cck[1]['value']);
```

Note that you are still passing an array, but the first item is a comma separated string.

Comment: I tried it... and it gives me the empty text

Comment: Have you tried the values manually in the view?

Comment: Yes... I tried manually in the view and no results... I think I should create the view again, because I cloned it from a view with an arguments configured not to take multiple items

Comment: Also make sure the query will work with multiple args. If you look at the query generated and paste it here I'm sure we can help.

Comment: I created a fresh view with the argument configured to take multiple items.SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   node.title AS node_title,
   node.language AS node_language,
   node_data_field_nombre_plan.field_nombre_plan_value AS node_data_field_nombre_plan_field_nombre_plan_value,
   node.type AS node_type,
   node.vid AS node_vid
 FROM node node 
 LEFT JOIN content_type_curso node_data_field_nombre_plan ON node.vid = node_data_field_nombre_plan.vid
 WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (node.type in ('curso')) AND (node_data_field_nombre_plan.field_nombre_plan_value = 'FIAB MADRID 2010, ALDEFE 2011')

Comment: Definitly not working.. the query should be at the end like this: (node_data_field_nombre_plan.field_nombre_plan_value = 'FIAB MADRID 2010' OR node_data_field_nombre_plan.field_nombre_plan_value = 'ALDEFE 2011')

Comment: It should us IN. I'm not quite sure why not. You could try + in stead of , otherwise it may be a problem with the field handler.

Comment: I also tried with +. Can you please create a view and see if on your side you can get it to work with multiple values? Thanks

Comment: I have tried with nid and it worked fine, just not with that field.

Comment: You did it with + or ,? The IDs are numbers... but my field contains text with spaces like 'Field Value 1'. You said something about a field handler... can you explain me more? I can't change the field to use numbers because of the database structure...

Comment: I think that this has evolved beyond the original question. It may be better to post another with your query about multiple arguments. It attract more attention than these comments.

Comment: Well, I was asking to know if my question was answered... but as it looks... that option does not work with text fields, only numbers

Comment: @JeremyFrench let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/736/discussion-between-sergiu-and-jeremy-french)

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with setting multiple arguments to contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

I had checked: Allow multiple values

I had checked Specify validation criteria and that was the problem as it has its own setting for filter value type that in my case was Term IDs separated by , or +