# set multiple taxonomy values programmatically

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view that has a "Has taxonomy term ID" contextual filter and also a nid contextual  filter.

I execute this view programmatically, but I need to pass also multiple values for the taxonomy contextual filter.

I tried this:

```
$view->set_arguments(array($tid, $nid));
$view->execute();
```

and it works only if $tid is only a number.

I tried to put more than one tid using "+", but it doesn't work. 
(example 3+5+8)

Any idea on how I can set a multiple taxonomy argument programmatically?
thank you in advance

---

**I found a solution, but I don't like it**. I removed the filter from contextual filter and I added an exposed filter for the same field. Then I changed the code in this way:

```
$view->set_arguments(array($nid));
$view->exposed_input['field_myfield_tid'] = $tid;  //note that $tid is an array of tid
$view->execute();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set multiple items for an argument in embeded view](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/set-multiple-items-for-an-argument-in-embeded-view)

Comment: thank you, but I think that it is not. I have no problem in passing multiple arguments (look at: array($tid, $nid)). Here the problem is related on how to pass multiple values for the same argument ($tid = $tid1 . "+" . $tid2 . "+" etc.)

Comment: Separate multiple terms with a plus sign. I have tried it and worked. 
`$view->set_arguments(array('23+4585+84', 123)); // 123 is the NID`

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement the "hook_views_pre_view" function in order to alter the contextual filter arguments of your view and display. In order to add multiple taxonomy values for the same argument, you can change the $args[0] element from the $args variable of the hook.
For example: $args[0] = '22+14+64';
Remember to check the "Allow multiple values" option of the contextual filter.

Take into account that altering contextual filter arguments inside the previous hook may produce troubles when using a views exposed form. Specifically, the form "action" attribute may have a wrong URL. If that issue appears, you can solve it by implementing the "hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter" function and changing the $form['#action'] element with the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this requirement there are several methods , the first one is 
in your Taxonomy Contextual filter  enable **Specify validation criteria** 
and put **Filter value type** on `Term IDs separated by , or +`,

[image]

with this settings the following code will works for you.

```
   $tid = "3,4,5"; // or  $tid = "3+4+5";
   $view->set_arguments(array($tid, $nid)); $view->execute();
```